# std::atomic load method decreases the reference count when used with std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, atomic

I would like to use a `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>` in my code so that the shared_ptr can be atomicaly updated, but I have a problem when accessing the shared_ptr. The load() method on the atomic seems to reduce the ref-count on the shared_ptr, so that I can't actually use the object without it being deallocated.

Here is a simplified piece of code that shows the problem...

```
typedef shared_ptr<MyClass> MyClassPtr;
typedef atomic<MyClassPtr> MyClassAtomicPtr;

// 1.
MyClassPtr ptr( new MyClass() );
printf("1. use_count=%d\n", ptr.use_count());

// 2. 
MyClassAtomicPtr atomicPointer(ptr);
printf("2. use_count=%d\n", ptr.use_count());

// 3.
{
    MyClassPtr p = atomicPointer.load();
    printf("3a. use_count=%d\n", ptr.use_count());
}
printf("3b. use_count=%d\n", ptr.use_count());

// 4.
{
    MyClassPtr p = atomicPointer.load();
    printf("4a. use_count=%d\n", ptr.use_count());
}
printf("4b. use_count=%d\n", ptr.use_count());
```

The output of this is:

```
1. use_count=1
2. use_count=2
3a. use_count=2
3b. use_count=1
4a. use_count=1
4b. use_count=-572662307
```

I understand steps 1 and 2. But at step 3, I would expect the assignment to the shared_ptr to increase the ref-count to 3, and then when it goes out of scope for the ref-count to go back down to 2. But in fact it stays at 2 when assigned and then decreases to 1 when the shared_ptr goes out of scope. Similarly in step 4, where the ref-count goes to zero and the object is deleted.

So my question is: how can I access and use the shared_ptr managed by the atomic without destroying it?

(I was compiling with Visual Studio 2012 Version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL)

Comment: There is a C++(17?) standard design proposal for atomic_shared_ptr by Herb Sutter, the document also explains the drawbacks of the existing approach: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4162.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the standard way to atomically load and store shared pointers are to use the functions in §20.7.2.5[util.smartptr.shared.atomic]. It seems only libc++ of clang support them:

```
template<class T> bool atomic_is_lock_free(const shared_ptr<T>* p);
template<class T> shared_ptr<T> atomic_load(const shared_ptr<T>* p);
template<class T> shared_ptr<T> atomic_load_explicit(const shared_ptr<T>* p, memory_order mo);
template<class T> void atomic_store(shared_ptr<T>* p, shared_ptr<T> r);
template<class T> void atomic_store_explicit(shared_ptr<T>* p, shared_ptr<T> r, memory_order mo);
template<class T> shared_ptr<T> atomic_exchange(shared_ptr<T>* p, shared_ptr<T> r);
template<class T> shared_ptr<T> atomic_exchange_explicit(shared_ptr<T>* p, shared_ptr<T> r, memory_order mo);
template<class T> bool atomic_compare_exchange_weak(shared_ptr<T>* p, shared_ptr<T>* v, shared_ptr<T> w);
template<class T> bool atomic_compare_exchange_strong(shared_ptr<T>* p, shared_ptr<T>* v, shared_ptr<T> w);
template<class T> bool atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(shared_ptr<T>* p, shared_ptr<T>* v, shared_ptr<T> w, memory_order success, memory_order failure);
template<class T> bool atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(shared_ptr<T>* p, shared_ptr<T>* v, shared_ptr<T> w, memory_order success, memory_order failure);
```

So you code could be written as:

```
auto ptr = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
printf("1. use_count=%d\n", ptr.use_count());

{
    auto p = std::atomic_load(&ptr);
    printf("3a. use_count=%d\n", ptr.use_count());
}

printf("3b. use_count=%d\n", ptr.use_count());

{
    auto p = std::atomic_load(&ptr);
    printf("3a. use_count=%d\n", ptr.use_count());
}

printf("4b. use_count=%d\n", ptr.use_count());
```

But I can't find such supports listed on MSDN, so the best you could do is to use a mutex. (Actually, the implementation of these functions in libc++ uses a mutex too.)

Comment: Thank you. I had tried the atomic_load() functions as well, and I had seen that they didn't work either. As you say, it looks like they do not have the specializations for shared_ptr that they are supposed to have in VS2012. If they were there though, would you have to call them using atomic_load(&ptr), or would it also work with an atomic<shared_ptr> as well?

Comment: My mistake: it looks to me as if the atomic_load specializations *are* there. This is from the `<memory>` header:
`shared_ptr<_Ty> atomic_load(const shared_ptr<_Ty> *_Ptr)`
and it looks like it's implemented with a spin_lock.

Comment: I can confirm that this does compile and run as expected with VC++ 2012 RTM – this is merely a documentation bug.

Answer (score 8):

You can't use `std::shared_ptr<T>` as template argument type for `std::atomic<T>`. "The type of the template argument T shall be trivially copyable." (§29.5 1 in N3290) `std::shared_ptr<T>` is not trivially copyable.

Apparently, in your example `std::memcpy` (or something like that) is used to copy the `std::shared_ptr` and afterwards the destructor is invoked. That's the reason for the decrementing reference count. In the last step, the object is deleted.

A solution is to use a `std::mutex` to protect your `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Rather than a mutex, use the free functions that manage atomic access to `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Thank you, nosid, for the explanation of why the ref-count was not working as I had expected. I imagine that if the template specializations were there (refered to in KennyTM's answer), that it would then work?

Comment: @Pete Becker: When you talk about the 'free functions' do you mean the atomic_load specializations discussed in KennyTM's answer, or something else? Unfortunately those specializations are not there with VS2012, but if there's another way to manage a (more efficient) atomic update to a shared_ptr without a mutex I would be very interested.

Comment: They are probably there; they're certainly in the code I wrote for Dinkumware, and that's the library that Microsoft ships. Try them and see; not being in MSDN means only that they're not in MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

Down in the guts of the implementation, the std::atomic ctor you're calling must be assigning its internal pointer with something like:

```
std::atomic(T* ctorInput) {
   memcpy(myPtr, ctorInput, sizeof(T));
}
```

What this means is that it doing a direct copy on the bytes, bypassing any real copy constructor "T(const T&)". That's why it only works correctly on a 'trivially copyable' type, namely one whose copy constructor doesn't do anything anyway. Since shared_ptr DOES do real work, namely an atomic increment, in its copy ctor that work isn't getting done by std::atomic because it never invokes the call. You then get a mysterious off-by-1 error in the reference count.

Answer (score 1):

In `C++20` MSVC (VS version `16.7`) supports `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>`.

Below I print out the reference counts after doing a few atomic `loads`.

*Note that neither clang nor gcc support this as of this writing.*

```
std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<int>> pointer{ std::make_shared<int>( 42 ) };

{
    auto p1{ pointer.load( ) };
    // Prints 2.
    std::cout << std::format( "Count: {}\n", p1.use_count( ) );
}

auto p2{ pointer.load( ) };
// Prints 2.
std::cout << std::format( "Count: {}\n", p2.use_count( ) );

// Prints 3.
auto p3{ pointer.load( ) };
std::cout << std::format( "Count: {}\n", p3.use_count( ) );
```